# Can items in Ansible loop or with_items be processed concurrently?

Tags: loops, ansible, concurrently

```yaml
- block:
    - name: ensure backup directory exists
      win_file:
        path: "{{ BACKUP }}"
        state: directory
        recurse: yes
    - include_tasks: increment_backup.yml
      with_items: "{{ filelist.stdout_lines }}"
  when: work_status.stat.exists
```

I just want these items be dealt with concurrently.
For example, there are 10 items within filelist.stdout_lines. What I wanna do is these 10 items can be processed parallel.
It's not task level. It's within one single task.
But I didn't find any clues from Ansible documents.

Does anybody know about this?

Comment: Are you aware of the [async docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/user_guide/playbooks_async.html)? It's unclear from your question which of the two (or even the `block` itself?) you want to run concurrently but I'd start by reading those docs and then edit your question to ask an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) question

Comment: @mdaniel, thanks for your reminder. I've just updated the description.

Comment: "ERROR! 'async' is not a valid attribute for a TaskInclude" says that what you are asking for is not possible; I also tried `- {include_tasks: {file: "", apply: {async: 10}}}` and got a similar error about "for a Block" -- I can see where they're coming from since async for a list of things can generate terrible race conditions, especially if one task has a `register:` on it or similar implicit dependency